# How permissions can be applied to all the pages in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, microsoft-forms

I have home page on which a button is there. On click of this button a new SharePoint page should open up that has Microsoft form to be filled and submitted.

The problem is I am sharing link of my home page with user. He is able to click on button.But new page that opens up is asking for user permission.

How can I make sure that person having link of home page is able to access all the subsequent pages and forms?

Comment: You need to share the Microsoft form with your users for that, check [this](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/send-a-form-and-collect-responses-2eaf3294-0cff-492d-884d-a1dee909e845).

Comment: Thanks. how does it work when i have 2-3 pages lined up. home page has 2 options to select for. on selection new page opens up which has 3 options to select from . on click of the button on page 2 third page opens up.

Comment: could you please also let me know how to hide certain text fields on selection of choice buttons (conditional viewing)

Comment: I have answered to your main question below. If it helps you please upvote ( ^ ) and [accept it as an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Comment: For your another question of hiding some text fields, you need give us some details about it. which form you are using? OOTB SharePoint list form or any other custom form like powerapps/InfoPath. Which version of SharePoint you are using.

Comment: I think creating a new question and adding detailed requirements will be better for your 2nd question.

Answer (score 0):

Find out the folder which has the SharePoint pages in your site and check the folder permission. All the user of your site at least should have read access to the folder, so that the same will be applied to the pages inside the folder. As @Ganesh said authentication setting for the Microsoft forms should as be checked, refer this [link](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/send-a-form-and-collect-responses-2eaf3294-0cff-492d-884d-a1dee909e845)

Comment: thanks it worked

Comment: Glad to know that, If my answer has helped you, then kindly mark it as an answer, so that it will help others too in future :)

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding you are creating pages for 2nd and 3rd level, So I think those pages will be stored on your site somewhere in **Site Pages**, **Pages** or **Site Assets** library.

For Example: My page URL is `https://domain.sharepoint.com/sites/sitename/SitePages/Page1.aspx` then this page with name `Page1.aspx` is stored in **Site Pages** library (Which you can see from **Site Contents** page).

If users are not able to access those pages then you need to check the permissions for that particular library. You can check the permissions on list/library from **List/Library settings**.

In order to see the pages, user should have at least **Read** permission.

**Reference**:

1. [Customize permissions for a SharePoint list or library](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/customize-permissions-for-a-sharepoint-list-or-library-02d770f3-59eb-4910-a608-5f84cc297782).
2. [Understanding permission levels in SharePoint](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/understanding-permission-levels).

**Note**: Also make sure that user is having permission on the **Microsoft form** or you need to share your form with the users you are targeting. Check the reference, [Send a form and collect responses](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/send-a-form-and-collect-responses-2eaf3294-0cff-492d-884d-a1dee909e845).